# External CSS file not working when opened in browser

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I created a webpage on codepen and I've tried to shift it over to Atom and launch it in the browser from there. The html is loading in the browser but my CSS is having no effect. It is in the same directory as my index file, so I'm stumped as to why it isn't working. I'll include the html and css files in a link so you can see the whole picture..

Here's the [html](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14651974186275791399) and here's the [css](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=78502901971401318590)

I'm sure I'm either doing something wrong or missing something simple. Thanks in advance for any time taken to help out.

Comment: How about just share your codepen link, instead of uploading html to another site?

Comment: Because my codepen code works fine, and I've edited the HTML in Atom. The problem is with my code in Atom and how it isn't translating to the browser.

Comment: It's not a question about CSS or HTML itself, it's a question about Atom. If you simply launch webpage from your desktop, without opening Atom, it works as it should. So, edit your tags. Remove "browser" and add "Atom". And edit your question to make it easier to understand for another Atom users.

Comment: I will edit the tags my apologies. Turns out it was nothing to do with Atom it was me not realising SCSS isn't recognised by browsers and needs to be translated to CSS

Comment: Maybe you are getting CORS errors. Check your console

Answer (score 0):

I was missing something simple. The CSS was being preprocessed on codepen through SCSS. I needed to compile it into regular CSS to have it show in the browser.